# C++ Returning a Reference of an Object

Tags: c++, return-by-reference

I'm currently in a C++ Course and im struggling with References. I know there are some similar topics, but i couldnt find an answer for this.
The thing is my Prof wants us to use  References when returning objects, so return by value or using a pointer as return  is no option.
So i guess  i have to use a dynamic allocated object (returning a reference to a local object ends in a mess...right?)

```
1. Complex& method() {
2. Complex *object = new Complex();
3. return *object; }
```

Here is where im struggling, how do i catch the return right?

```
1. Complex one = object.method();
```

As far as i understand, with this i will get only a Copy and a Memory Leak
So how do i catch it with a pointer?

```
1. Complex *two = new Complex();
2. delete two;
3. *two = object.method();
```

this seems to work, but is there a way of it in just one line? Or should it be done different?

Comment: None of them works. Either of your examples is calling undefined behavior.

Comment: You would store it in a reference? `Complex &two = object.method();`, and then later `delete &two;`. Note that deleting an object through a reference is unusual - normally people use pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my Prof wants us to use References when returning objects

When I read this, my first thought was that your professor meant:

```
void method(Complex& nonConstPassByReference) 
{
    nonConstPassByReference.data = 10;
}
```

or

```
int method(Complex& nonConstPassByReference) 
{
    nonConstPassByReference.data = 10;
    return (0);  // no error occurred
}
```

And when I use this technique, I now use

```
std::string method(Complex& nonConstPassByReference) 
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    nonConstPassByReference.data = 10;
    // more stuff
    if (anErrorOccurred) 
       ss << errorDescriptionInfo << std::endl;
    return (ss.str());  // no error occurred when return size is 0
}
```

This comes from the idea that, in general, all methods or functions can have two kinds of formal parameters.  We call them pass-by-value, and pass-by-reference.

In general, all functions / methods can have both input and output formal parameters.  And usually, input parameters are pass-by-value.  Output parameters are non-const-pass-by-reference, inviting the method body to send its results back to the prebuilt instance of the calling code.

Occasionally, pass-by-reference variables are used for 'input-to-method' parameters (perhaps for performance - to avoid an expensive copy). In this case, the input-to-method-pass-by-reference parameters should be marked with 'const', to ask the compiler to generate an error if the code tries to modify that input.

Note that many C functions do NOT return a value which is part of the action ... return is instead an 'error occurred' indication, with the error description stashed in errno.

Answer (score 3):

One idea is to store the returned object inside your object:

```
class Obj {
public:
  Complex &method() { c.data = 10; return c; }
private:
  Complex c;
};
```

This way there isn't any returning of local variable, or heap allocation.

Answer (score 3):

returning a reference is efficient when you returning class member,

like:

```
class A{
  Complex member;
public:
  Complex& method(){
    return member;
  }
};
```

You also can return reference in manner to return some static or global object that can't be NULL, like:

```
Complex& method() {
     static Complex c; // c cant be null
     return c;
}
```

the advantage of using reference is that you can use the function call as an object, like: `cin>>method().real>>method().img;` and use the same object even if you call the method several times.
 But your code doesn't feet to use reference, because each call creates a new instance.

if you are using dynamic allocation you should return a pointer:

```
Complex* method() {
   return new Complex();
}
```

and you should remember to delete it.